# Swagger error on .net core 3.0 webapi on windows (Unable to resolve service for type 'ISwaggerProvider' )

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

I have this default Web APi scaffolding . i included following Nuget packages. i have the following file in Startup.cs. however it is throwing error. please assist

[image: nuget packages installed]
[image: error on screen]

My Startup.cs class has the following:-

```
            app.UseSwagger();

            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.RoutePrefix = "v1";
                var basePath = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(c.RoutePrefix) ? "." : "..";
                c.SwaggerEndpoint($"{basePath}/swagger/{c.RoutePrefix}/swagger.json", "Name");
            });
```

Comment: error: InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.ISwaggerProvider' while attempting to Invoke middleware 'Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you are having this problem is because you are not calling `services.AddSwaggerGen()` in your `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` method.

This method registers the `ISwaggerProvider` interface in the DI container , since it isn't registered you are receiving this exception when invoking your swagger route.

Full example of swagger section in `ConfigureServices` :

```
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });
        });
```

Comment: I tried that but now the Swagger page itself is not opening.

Comment: error: 
This localhost page can’t be foundNo webpage was found for the web address: https://localhost:44316/swagger
HTTP ERROR 404

Comment: @rahul , you are specifying the route prefix property to be `c.RoutePrefix = "v1";`. Therefore your swagger is available at localhost:44316/v1 .

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. it fixed my issue :-)

Comment: @rahul you should accept this answer as correct if it helped resolve your issue.

Comment: One more query ...... i have to pass parameters and header values to the API from Swagger webpage...how do i do that. Is there a config file i can update (right now there is no JSON or YAML file attaced to the project)